# .net core 2.0 console app : exe file location

Tags: .net-core, console-application, desktop-application

I am working with .net core 2.0 console application. I need to run this console app using command prompt.

Like,
MyApp.exe arguments

I published the console app using below command to generate .exe :

dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64

It creates multiple .exe file,

1) \bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64 
2) \bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\publish

I believe both are same and I can use (2) as published version of the app. Correct me if wrong.
I am not sure why it generates .exe at (1) and does not contain bunch of dlls at there.
What is the difference?

anyone can give me more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is still a framework-dependent deployment, it used when you call `dotnet run -r win-x64`. It resolves and configures the shared framework via the information in `.runtimeconfig.json` and your `PATH` environment variable and locates the DLLs via a values in the `.runtimeconfig.dev.json` and `.deps.json` based on your global packages cache (=> specific to your machine and user).

For deploying self-contained applications, the publish folder contains all the necessary assets. The host uses the local dlls instead of the shared framework and as well as the necessary DLLs.

Comment: Got it. It was really helpful. Thank you so much for the answer !!